# When is it safe to sell books and contracts?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm sure most people have answered this for themselves (because this inventory UI is so limited), but now that I have dozens of books and contracts in my inventory, am I safe to vendor trash all of them once I read them? Is there any risk to shedding one that I'll need later?

Comment: This isn't worth it's own answer, but as a general rule, anything you CAN sell is safe to sell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did trash many books and notes on my first playthrough, and I didn't notice any case where I needed something later. As you said, you should read them all beforehand as they might trigger quest advances or give you bestiary entries.

One item I'd be careful is the pass to get across the Pontar, it looks similar to other notes and you might want to keep it.

You could also restrict selling books and notes to one particular merchant, that way it is easier to buy something back if you actually need to.

Comment: It would be nice to have something like in the game Skyrim: A little house with as many bookshelfs you need for all your collected books. Looks great and you never have to ask you: Where is my book XY.

Comment: Actually there is one quest in Skellige where you have to bring certain books to an NPC.  I'm not sure if the relevant titles are flagged as quest items before/after you purchase them (especially if you happen to come across any of the books before picking up the quest).

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to sell Sell books.
1.They are heavy.
2.Once read, they stay read, even if you find another of the same title later in the game.
3.Any books or letters needed for quests will be under the quest tool tab, not books.
4.Glossary/Codex (just like Dragon Age)